# Grant a user select, insert, update, delete to a specfic schema

Tags: oracle

I would like to grant a user i have created the permissions : select, insert, update, delete on a specific schema.

Do I need to be in the schema to do it ? (alter session set current_schema='my_schema';)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

User often are asking for a single statement to Grant privileges in a single step.

there are multiple workarounds for not have a GRANT SELECT on all table

```
FOR x IN (SELECT * FROM user_tables)
LOOP   
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT ON ' || x.table_name || ' TO <<someone>>'; 
END LOOP;
```

or

```
declare
cursor c1 is select table_name from user_tables;
cmd varchar2(200);
begin
for c in c1 loop
cmd := 'GRANT SELECT ON '||c.table_name|| <<TO YOURUSERNAME>>;
execute immediate cmd;
end loop;
end;
```

Oracle could implement a schema level grant

```
GRANT SELECT ON <schema name> to <<user>>
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply, but do I need to change to the schema with "alter session set current_schema" to do this ?

Comment: exec for i in (select table_name from user_tables) loop execute immediate 'grant select,insert,update,delete on '||i.table_name||' to TOTO'; end loop; and I get the error ORA-00942. Any idea ?

Comment: it causes that error because You tried to execute a SQL statement that references a table or view that either does not exist, that you do not have access to, or that belongs to another schema and you didn't reference the table by the schema name.